# Method for reducing memory load of Spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark program with calculates relations between users, i.e. it receives data set of type:

```
RDD[(java.lang.Long, Map[(String, String), Integer])]
```

Where the Long is timestamp, and the map is a score relevant to tuples of two users. and should run some function over the scores and return the following type:

```
Map[String, Map[java.lang.Long, java.lang.Double]]
```

Where the String is the first String in the tuple, and the map is the results of the function per timeslot.

In my case I have around 2000 users so the maps I receive are quite big (2000^2 per timeslot), and also the results relies on the previous timeslot results.

I am running the program locally and receiving `GC overhead limit exceeded`. I increased the heap memory to 14g using: `-Xmx14G` in vmarguments (I see the java process is occupying more than 12g of memory) but it didn't help.

**Currently implemented method**

I have tried several directions to decrease the memory consumption and currently came up with the following idea: since every timestamp relies only on the previous one I will collect every timeslot separately and keep the previous results on driver. In this manner I will run calculations only on part of the data and hopefully it will not crush the program.

The code:

```
def calculateScorePerTimeslot(scorePerTimeslotRDD: RDD[(java.lang.Long, Map[(String, String), Integer])]): Map[String, Map[java.lang.Long, java.lang.Double]] = {
   var distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD = distancesPerTimeslotRDD.groupBy(_._1).sortBy(_._1)
   println("Start collecting all the results - cache the data!!")
   distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.cache()
   println("Caching all the data has completed!")

   while(!distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.isEmpty())
   {
     val dataForTimeslot: (java.lang.Long, Iterable[(java.lang.Long, Map[(String, String), Integer])]) = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.first()
     println("Retrieved data for timeslot: " + dataForTimeslot._1)

     //Code which is irrelevant for question - logic

     println("Removing timeslot: " + dataForTimeslot._1)
     distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.filter(t => !t._1.equals(dataForTimeslot._1))
     println("Filtering has complete! - without: " + dataForTimeslot._1)
   }
}
```

Summary: Basically, the idea is to extract one timeslot at a time process it and save the results at driver - in this manner I try to reduce the size of data which passes on `collect`.

**Reason I write this post**

Unfortunately, this doesn't help me and the program still dies. My question is: is this manner of taking the first() item of a RDD and then filter it have the effect of iterating over the items on RDD? Are there other better ideas to tackle this kinds of question (better ideas which are not increasing the memory or moving to a real distributed cluster)?

Comment: For starters don't `groupBy` especially when you follow it by another shuffle (`sortBy`).

Comment: @zero323 Hi thanks for the answer, TBH I have read a similar comment in the documentation half an hour ago and changed it to aggregateByKey. Thx for the heads up!

Comment: If you perform the same operation (grouping data without reducing) it is at least as bad and typically worse than groupBy.

Comment: @zero323 I couldn't fully understand the second comment, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If you use `aggregateByKey` to group data it will be even less efficient than `groupBy` / `groupByKey`. Simply avoid large aggregated structures no matter what method you use.

Comment: @zero323 thx, will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `RDD[(java.lang.Long, Map[(String, String), Integer])]` uses more memory than `RDD[(java.lang.Long, Array[(String, String, Integer)])]`.  You'll save some memory if you can use the latter.

Secondly, your loop is pretty inefficient in caching data.  Always call `unpersist` on any RDD you no longer need.

```
distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.cache()
var rddSize = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.count()
println("Caching all the data has completed!")

while(rddSize > 0) {
  val prevRDD = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD 

  val dataForTimeslot = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.first()
  println("Retrieved data for timeslot: " + dataForTimeslot._1)

  // Code which is irrelevant for answer - logic

  println("Removing timeslot: " + dataForTimeslot._1)
  // Cache the new value of distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD
  distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.filter(t => !t._1.equals(dataForTimeslot._1)).cache()

  // Force calculation so we can throw away previous iteration value
  rddSize = distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD.count()
  println("Filtering has complete! - without: " + dataForTimeslot._1)

  // Get rid of previously cached RDD
  prevRDD.unpersist(false)
}
```

Thirdly, you can try using [Kryo Serializer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization), though this sometimes makes things worse. You have to configure the serializer and [replace `cache` with `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#serialized-rdd-storage)

Comment: Thx for the answer, you raised some interesting points, I will look into applying all of them and currently I already run a test with #2. I do have a question, in #2 you cache a RDD and later you unpersist the same RDD (as the loop advances), so basically you cache the RDD for just one iteration of the loop? or I am missing something here?

Comment: When you do filter on `distancesPerTimeslotVarRDD`, it creates a new RDD. The next iteration will refer to this new RDD, not the original one. You should cache the new RDD and throw the original cache away, since it's no longer useful in the next iteration.